# Is there a way to convert this weird matrix into a table in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, powerquery

I am aware of the transpose and unpivot functions available in Excel and PowerQuery but I'm not sure how to apply it to this kind of weird matrix with two column and row headers.

For example the data looks like this:

| xxxxxx | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | FY 2017 | FY 2017 | FY 2018 | FY 2018 | ... | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REGION | PRODUCT CATEGORY | INDUSTRY | DEALER | INDUSTRY | DEALER | ... | ... |
| CAN | SEDAN | 5 | 2 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| CAN | TRUCK | 3 | 1 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| USA | SEDAN | 6 | 2 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| USA | TRUCK | 9 | 3 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

This data is made up but it's the same format as what I'll be working with. The goal is to produce a table/list so I can actually work with it and make PivotTables/Charts

| FY | REGION | PROD CAT | INDUSTRY | DEALER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2017 | CAN | SEDAN | 5 | 2 |
| 2017 | CAN | TRUCK | 3 | 1 |
| 2017 | USA | SEDAN | 6 | 2 |
| 2017 | USA | TRUCK | 9 | 3 |
| 2018 | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Does anyone know how I should get started?

Thank you!

I've tried transposing data in Excel and UnPivot in PowerQuery, but the data gets all messed up. I suspect because it has 2 title row headers and 2 category columns

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle checkmark to accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Revised code

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
FirstTwoRows = Table.FirstN(Source ,2),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(FirstTwoRows),
NewColumnHeaders = Table.AddColumn(#"Transposed Table", "Custom", each [Column2]&"|"&[Column1]??[Column2])[Custom],
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns(Table.Skip(Source,2),List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(Table.Skip(Source,2)),NewColumnHeaders})),
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Rename, {"REGION", "PRODUCT CATEGORY"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"|"}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"Attribute.1", "Attribute.2"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Attribute.1", type text}, {"Attribute.2", type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Attribute.1]), "Attribute.1", "Value", List.Sum)
in #"Pivoted Column"
```

Bring the initial data into Powerquery with NO Headers (or demote them first)

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I realized I should have clarified that the original table is much larger. Is it possible to modify your code so it carries over the next columns?

Comment: Edited answer above